# Unable to download debconf preconfiguration file

Tags: server, system-installation, debconf

I'm using ipxe to network boot many machines. I do not wish to provide a debconf file specific to any single machine. To accomplish this ipxe is passing in many parameters into the installer to make installs unattended.
My debconf file is automatically generated by hitting a specific url like the following:

```
set theKernelParams auto=true fb=false  interface=${mac} priority=critical  url=http://ipxe/ubuntuks.php?ip=${ip}&repo=${repo}&version=${UBUNTUVERSION}
```

What the url= will resolve to is:
`'http://ipxe/ubuntuks.php?ip=192.168.1.250&repo=http://repo/ubuntu/18.04/os/x86_64&version=18.04'`

The idea being that we can make a configuration on the fly and downloaded to the system installing ubuntu.

However!
While installing, I get an error informing me that debconf can't retrieve the preconfiguration file.
[image]

I have this working on ESXI, redhat, centos, openSUSE, WINDOWS(Didn't see that one coming). The only outlier here is Debian and Ubuntu.
 1. Yes I've checked that the url resolves.
 2. Yes I've checked that the server isn't returning an error.
 3. Yes I can get a valid configuration back using curl or wget.

The question is:

- How do I debug this so that I can see what ubuntu doesn't like about
  the file?
- How can I fix the issue so that my automatically generated
  files are consumed correctly.
- How can I avoid the error?

Comment: I'd add the ipxe tag, but I don't have the rep...

Comment: The plot thickens.. Gaining access to the console, I can plainly see that the Ethernet is clearly not truly enabled. I am only able to ping my local address and nothing else.

Comment: It would appear that ubuntu is not appending the domainname being returned from dhcp to the hostname of the file I am attempting to retrieve.  Using the FQDN seems to work, but now the question is, why isn't ubuntu appending the domain name when doing name lookups.

Comment: Yep confirmed.. this looks like a bug. While attempting to install, the domain name which is plainly returned by the dhcp server is not used in the lookup of addresses.